# Laravel Voyager: deleting all default bread for tables

Tags: php, laravel, voyager

When I installed voyager, I cleaned up all the default BREADs such as users and roles to just begin my work from scratch and then when I tried to go roles tab on the dashboard I got an error:

> ( **ErrorException**: Trying to get property of non-object )

and also the **Menu Builder** in the provided dropdown box **tools** that comes with Voyager gives an error

> **NotFoundHttpException**

when visiting this route:

> **http://localhost:8000/admin/menus**

**Is it happening because I have deleted a BREAD that I should not have deleted.** ?

Answer (score 0):

Attempting to delete data manually may end up introducing errors, because you might delete data used or referenced somewhere.

If you don't want **dummy data** with your installation, install Voyager without **dummy data**, rather than manually deleting the data yourself.

Use the following command to install Voyager without **dummy data**:

```
php artisan voyager:install
```

Adding the **--with-dummy** flag installs with **dummy data**:

```
php artisan voyager:install --with-dummy
```

Comment: i installed it without dummy data, but some breads for some tables like pages, menus, users exist and if i deleted one of them errors  appeared everywhere e.g when i deleted menus bread and checking my route:list i found no route points to /admin/menus and all associated links and routes to menus so errors appear when i try for example go to menu builder but i don't understand why there must be a bread for menu despite the tcg Menu model exists whether there was a bread or not ?